# Moving variable of type short into EAX using __asm in c++(VS 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly

When using asm insertions in c++ (Visual Studio 2010), I get an "incompatible types" error when i try to move 16 bit variable of type short into the 32bit EAX register. However everything works fine if i use the 16 bit AX register. What is the logic behind this error? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   short sVar;

   std::cout << "sVar=";
   std::cin >> sVar;

   __asm
   {
      MOV AX, sVar;
      SHL AX, 1;
      MOV sVar, AX;
   }
   std::cout << sVar << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic is simple - `eax` is 32-bit and `short` is 16-bit, so you can't copy one into another because they are of different sizes. `ax` is 16-bit, so `short` can be copied there no problem. You can then use `movzx` or `movsx` to widen the 16-bit value to 32 bits with either zero or sign extension.

Comment: earlier versions of assembly had no problems with it (correct me if im wrong). is it "inline assembly"-specific error? Thank you!

Comment: @Vis Viva: I guess those earlier versions would just coerce the pointer to the variable and you would read whatever happened at adjucent addresses.

Answer (score 0):

EAX is 32 bits and sVar (short) is 16 bits. In this case you need to look into MOVSX (move with sign extend) or MOVZX (move with zero extend).